# How to call function in {if} statement if the entrybox is empty?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am going to write program that calculate just a number with (123) and show sum of them to me. But i want write a code that when (sum) button pressed do this:{if the field doesn't have any integer type of number call errorMsg function and else calculate numbers} but I don't know how can I do this. Please help!

```
from tkinter import *
frame = Tk()
def textBoxes():
    global e1      
    e1 = Entry(frame,justify=LEFT )

def labels():  
    var1 = StringVar()
    var1.set("Enter first number: ")
    label1 = Label(frame, textvariable = var1)
    var3=StringVar()   
def errorMsg():
    msg = messagebox.showinfo("Please Enter Some Number!")      
def calculator():    
    #def __init__(self,String_value1,String_value2,sum_result)
    String_value1 = e1.get()
    Int_value1 = int(String_value1)    

   if not(String_value1.get()):
       errorMsg()
   else:
       sum_result = Int_value1 + 123   

def buttons():
    B1 = Button(frame, text="Sum", command=calculator)

buttons()
labels()
textBoxes()
frame.mainloop()
```

Comment: You should really reduce this down to a [MCVE]

Comment: what does it mean?

Comment: Click the link. Try to reduce the code down to a smaller example. The question isn't very clear.

Comment: Okey Thanks. I am going to do that

Comment: Removed excessive tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your calculator method, instead of checking if it's empty or not, try to operate on your value and catch the exceptions if it fails. It is called [Easier to ask for forgiveness than permission](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html).

```
result = StringVar()
def calculator():  
    try:
        user_input = int(e1.get())   
        result.set(str(user_input+123)) #or however you like to show this
    except ValueError:
        errorMsg()
```

Little snippet, using your code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox

frame = tk.Tk()
var1 = tk.StringVar()
var3 = tk.StringVar()
ent1 = tk.Entry(frame,justify="left")
var1.set("Enter first number: ")
var3.set("Result")

def textBoxes():
    ent1.pack()

def labels():
    tk.Label(frame, textvariable=var3).pack()
    tk.Label(frame, textvariable=var1).pack()

def errorMsg():
    messagebox.showinfo("Error", "Please enter a valid number!")

def calculator():  
    try:
        user_input = int(ent1.get())   
        var3.set("Result = "+str(user_input+123))
    except ValueError:
        var3.set("Please enter a valid number!")
        errorMsg()

def buttons():
    tk.Button(frame, text="Sum", command=calculator).pack()

labels()
textBoxes()
buttons()

frame.mainloop()
```